# Blazor InputText value doesnt go to form POST when populated in jQuery

Tags: jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using a Leaflet map and have a click event in jQuery that gets the latitude and longitude of the clicked location and populates 2 textboxes in a Blazor server-side form.

When I click submit the latitude and longitude values in the model are null. If I was to type the lat/lng in to the form it gets passed through.

**jQuery**

```
var marker = {};

    function addMarker(e) {
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lng = e.latlng.lng;

        if (marker != undefined) {
            map.removeLayer(marker);
        };

        marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);

        $('#latitude').val(lat);
        $('#longitude').val(lng);
    }
```

**Blazor Form**

```
<EditForm Model="@ItemLocationModel">
                <input type="hidden" @bind-value="@ItemLocationModel.Id" />
                <div role="alert">Select the item you wish to trade from the list below.</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="jjj">Item</label>
                    <select id="category" class="form-control" @bind="@ItemLocationModel.ItemId">
                        <option value="">-- Select Item --</option>
                        @if (Items == null)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @foreach (var cnt in Items)
                            {
                                <option value="@cnt.Id">@cnt.Name</option>
                            }
                        }

                    </select>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ItemLocationModel.ItemId)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="newformap" class="newformap map-home" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
                    <InputText id="latitude" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@ItemLocationModel.Latitude" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ItemLocationModel.Latitude)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
                    <InputText id="longitude" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@ItemLocationModel.Longitude" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ItemLocationModel.Longitude)" />
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => HandleValidSubmit())">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </EditForm>
```

**HandleValidSubmit method**

```
private async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    if (ItemLocationModel.Id == 0)
    {
        // Add
        ForagingItemLocationObject.UserId = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("userid");

        await Http.PostJsonAsync("api/item/addlocation", ItemLocationModel);
    }
    else
    {
        // Update
        ItemLocationModel.UserId = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("userid");

        await Http.PostJsonAsync("api/item/updatelocation", ItemLocationModel);
    }

    await CloseTaskModal();
    DataChanged?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Blazor is a SPA application. The Blazor app's HTML is loaded within the app element of the root, index.html or _host.cshtml. This means the page isn't completely rendered when jQuery executes. Therefore $('#latitude') and $('#longitude') are likely undefined when you try to get their values. You'll need to set up an initialize method that triggers OnAfterRender so the values are available to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change an input value that is "controlled" by blazor using javascript isn't recommended. If you really need really need to change the value of an input, you should call a method in your blazor component that will update that value.

You should do something like

```
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateLatitudeValue', lat);
```

Where you have

```
public void UpdateMessageValue(string lat){
   @ItemLocationModel.Latitude = lat;
}
```

You could also pass an object for geo locations or what ever you want, but you should [Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to update the value from the input.